# Ant Build Android Project With Dependencies

Tags: android, ant, continuous-integration, jenkins

I'm trying to build an app (let's call it `android-app`) with a dependency on an SDK (let's call it `sdk`) via Ant. Eclipse is not installed on this computer (for reasoning, it's a CI box with Jenkins).

Both projects are in two completely separate directories side by side. `android-app` is in the directory `~/.jenkins/jobs/android-app/workspace` and `sdk` is in the directory `~/.jenkins/jobs/sdk/workspace`.

Let's assume both projects are "vanilla" and have not been built with Ant before. I `cd` to the `../android-app/workspace` directory and run `android update project -p . --library ~/.jenkins/jobs/sdk/workspace` which passes. I then `cd` to the `../sdk/workspace` directory and run `android update project -p .` which also passes.

At this point I `cd` back to the `../android-app/workspace` directory and run `ant clean build`. It fails with the error:

```
BUILD FAILED
/path/to/ant/build.xml:440: 
/path/to/sdk/workspace resolve to a path with no project.properties file for 
project /path/to/android-app/workspace
```

... where `/path/to` is the full path to the directories. I simplified it here.

If I `cd` to the `sdk` workspace and open `project.properties`, I receive the following:

```
# ProGuard
proguard.config=proguard.cfg

# Project target.
target=android-10
android.library=true
```

It does exist. So do all of these files:

[image: ls]

So, why is this failing? What am I doing wrong? I tried to provide as many details as possible. Please let me know if I can provide anything additional.

Comment: Does local.properties file contain: sdk.dir={path to your sdkfolder}?

Comment: Also,  check that in your project.properties file you have something like : android.library.reference.1={relative path to shared lib codebase}

Comment: @forgivegod Yes. `sdk.dir=/path/to/android-sdk-macosx`

Comment: @forgivegod I am going for an absolute path since they are in two completely different directories. `android.library.reference.1=/Users/jamescmartinez/.jenkins/jobs/sdk/workspace`

Comment: damn...all that should work.  hop onto android chat, perhaps the room can help out better.

Comment: I was told that it should be a relative directory, so I changed that. It is now at the relative `sdk` directory. It gets past that initial error and now I get a compile error (though it builds fine in Eclipse).

Comment: What was you solution?

Comment: @JPM Just added an answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, I encounter this problem too.

I use strace to find out what the hell is going on and found that the path you specified in project.properties will be appended with your current folder path as its prefix.

For example,
/home/myfolder/project > ant debug

And the library you specified in project.properties is /path/to/library

Then, the path will become
/home/myfolder/project/path/to/library

Comment: So what is the solution in how to fix this?

Comment: In the case above, the solution is to specify the path in project.properties as: ../../../path/to/library

Comment: Awesome, fixed my problem. Google documentation says nothing about the path needing to be relative - gah!

Answer (score 2):

Just to fill in the answer gap here, my Java version was completely off. I'm super embarrassed.

Comment: Well that doesn't help as my java version is up to date.

Comment: @JPM Yeah, James's answer does not reflect what he says in the question comments, which is that "I was told that it should be a relative directory" (i.e., the other answer is correct).  "My Java version was completely off" seems to be  a meaningless "whatever, bye" type observation.

Comment: @goldilocks I'm more than happy to help debug your problem, but this was the answer to mine. I cannot accept an answer that did not lead me in the correct direction if it didn't solve my problem.

Comment: My (solved) problem was it's supposed to be a relative url.  Your comment to the other (previous) answer is, **"Awesome, fixed my problem. Google documentation says nothing about the path needing to be relative - gah!"** -- very true. You also say in the comments to the question that using a relative url "gets past that initial error".  *The "initial error" in this case is the problem you describe in your question,* which is what would lead other people here...

Comment: ...but this answer has to do nothing to do with that -- it's about a subsequent *and undescribed problem* (except for "now I get a compile error though it builds fine in Eclipse").  That's very misleading for people who come here with the problem you actually describe (vs. the one you don't, which if you wanted a Q&A for that, should have been done separately).

Comment: I'd probably change it to include the specific details of your problem and the steps you took to fix it. It may not be the case *every* user will make use of "my Java version was completely off".